# Plotly: How to set node positions in a Sankey Diagram?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

The sample data is as follows:

```py
unique_list = ['home0', 'page_a0', 'page_b0', 'page_a1', 'page_b1', 
               'page_c1', 'page_b2', 'page_a2', 'page_c2', 'page_c3']
sources = [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 7, 6]
targets = [3, 4, 4, 3, 5, 6, 8, 7, 8, 9, 9]
values = [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]
```

Using the sample code from [the documentation](https://plotly.com/python/sankey-diagram/)

```py
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Sankey(
    node = dict(
      pad = 15,
      thickness = 20,
      line = dict(color = "black", width = 0.5),
      label = unique_list,
      color = "blue"
    ),
    link = dict(
      source = sources,
      target = targets,
      value = values
  ))])

fig.show()
```

This outputs the following sankey diagram

[image]

However, I would like to get **all the values which end in the same number in the same vertical column**, just like how the leftmost column has all of it's nodes ending with a 0. I see in the [docs](https://plotly.com/python/sankey-diagram/#define-node-position) that it is possible to move the node positions, however I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to do it other than manually inputting x and y values. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In `go.Sankey()` set `arrangement='snap'` and adjust x and y positions in `x=<list>` and `y=<list>`. The following setup will place your nodes as requested.

**Plot:**

[image]

Please note that the y-values are not explicitly set in this example. As soon as there are more than one node for a common x-value, the y-values will be adjusted automatically for all nodes to be displayed in the same vertical position. If you *do* want to set all positions explicitly, just set `arrangement='fixed'`

**Edit:**

I've added a custom function `nodify()` that assigns identical x-positions to label names that have a common ending such as `'0'` in `['home0', 'page_a0', 'page_b0']`. Now, if you as an example change `page_c1` to `page_c2` you'll get this:

[image]

**Complete code:**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
unique_list = ['home0', 'page_a0', 'page_b0', 'page_a1', 'page_b1', 
               'page_c1', 'page_b2', 'page_a2', 'page_c2', 'page_c3']
sources = [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 7, 6]
targets = [3, 4, 4, 3, 5, 6, 8, 7, 8, 9, 9]
values = [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]


def nodify(node_names):
    node_names = unique_list
    # uniqe name endings
    ends = sorted(list(set([e[-1] for e in node_names])))
    
    # intervals
    steps = 1/len(ends)

    # x-values for each unique name ending
    # for input as node position
    nodes_x = {}
    xVal = 0
    for e in ends:
        nodes_x[str(e)] = xVal
        xVal += steps

    # x and y values in list form
    x_values = [nodes_x[n[-1]] for n in node_names]
    y_values = [0.1]*len(x_values)
    
    return x_values, y_values

nodified = nodify(node_names=unique_list)

# plotly setup
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Sankey(
      arrangement='snap',
      node = dict(
      pad = 15,
      thickness = 20,
      line = dict(color = "black", width = 0.5),
      label = unique_list,
      color = "blue",
     x=nodified[0],
     y=nodified[1]
    ),
    link = dict(
      source = sources,
      target = targets,
      value = values
  ))])

fig.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. It was really helpful, it helped in my case, too. I, however, do not understand why you have to specify y-s as well if you want to modify just x-s. In the case above, the result when skipping the line y=nodified[1] would be different.

Comment: @Lan It seems like plotly ignores the `x` argument unless you also include `y`. Similarly if `y` is simply an array of zeros. The final layout *does* seem to be affected by `y` values though. @vestland 's use of a constant 0.1 does seem to give the best results for me as well.