# How to specify x- and y-coordinates in plotly network graph?

Tags: plotly, networkx

I would like to create a network diagram in which I can specify the location of the nodes. The diagram would be with roughly 30 nodes and will have different communities resulting in something like this:

[Example for network graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJefn.png)

Is there a way to specify x- and y-coordinates in plotly network graphs?

I found a similar approach for Sankey diagrams with ploty and I was wondering if there is a way to set the coordinates so I can structure the network diagram:
[Plotly: How to set node positions in a Sankey Diagram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61152889/plotly-how-to-set-node-positions-in-a-sankey-diagram)

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Plotly does not directly support network graphs. Thus a Graph styled plot usually consists of multiple Scatter plots containing nodes and edges. Maybe habe a look at this [Tutorial Atricle](https://plotly.com/python/network-graphs/). You can explicitly set the coordinates of the nodes, in the tutorial networkx is used. To set node positions in networkx see [here](https://plotly.com/python/network-graphs/).