# How to locate nodes in the middle in plotly sankey diagram

Tags: python, plotly-python, sankey-diagram

With plotly sankey diagram I want to locate a node in the middle using code, but since this node does not have a flow for another node, plotly places it at the right end. I have the next code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig1 = go.Figure(
    go.Sankey(
        node={"label": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]},
        link={
            "source": [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2],
            "target": [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5],
            "value": [20, 10, 20, 20, 5, 15]
        }        
    )
)
fig1.show()
```

The output:
[image]

For example, for the image I would like to locate node *D* below nodes *B* and *C*.

Comment: Is this not a duplicate?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61152889/plotly-how-to-set-node-positions-in-a-sankey-diagram

Comment: yes!!, that it was I needed

Answer (score 0):

You can create groups of nodes using the [`groups`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/sankey/#sankey-node-groups) key in the `node` dictionary:

```
fig1 = go.Figure(
    go.Sankey(
        node={
             "label": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"],
             "groups": [[0], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]
        },
        link={
            "source": [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2],
            "target": [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5],
            "value": [20, 10, 20, 20, 5, 15]
        }        
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but gave me an error: `ValueError: 
    Invalid value of type 'builtins.int' received for the 'groups[0]' property of sankey.node
        Received value: 0

    The 'groups' property is an info array that may be specified as:
    * a 2D list where:
      The 'groups[i][j]' property is a number and may be specified as:
      - An int or float`

Comment: @gabriel11. I've never used plotly, so stabbing in the dark here. Updated with a better understanding of the docs.

Comment: The output merge the nodes in three groups, but I want them apart (splitted)

Comment: @gabriel11. Can you post a picture of what it looks like?

Answer (score 0):

This is not technically an answer as it uses another package ([pyAlluv](https://github.com/tools4digits/pyAlluv/)) that creates matplotlib figures.

The package needs to be installed directly from github, for example with:

```
pip install --upgrade --no-deps git+https://github.com/tools4digits/pyalluv.git
```

The example is an adaptation from one of the [existing examples](https://github.com/tools4digits/pyAlluv/blob/master/examples/alluvial_basic.py#L28):

```
import numpy as np
from pyalluv import Alluvial
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ext = [10, ]  # start at t1 with a single node containing 10 elements
flows = [[[5],  # flow form node 1 at t1 to node 1 at t2
          [2],  # flow from node 1 at t1 to node 2 at t2
          [3]],  # ...
         [[4, 0, 0],  # flows from nodes 1, 2, 3 at t2 to node 1 at t3
          [1, 0, 3]]]  # flows from nodes 1, 2, 3 at t2 to node 2 at t3
alluv = Alluvial(x=['t1', 't2', 't3'], flows=flows, ext=ext, width=0.2, yoff=0, layout=['top', 'optimized', 'top'])

plt.show()
```

[image]

However, note that the package is indicated to be *work in progress*

It allows for quite some customization, that is not really documented though:

```
from pyalluv import Alluvial
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ext = [10, ]
flows = [[[5],
          [2],
          [3]],
         [[4, 0, 0],
          [1, 0, 3]]]
alluv = Alluvial(ax=ax, x=['t1', 't2', 't3'], flowprops={'fc':'gray', 'alpha':0.4}, ec='gray')
diag0 = alluv.add(flows=flows, ext=ext, width=0.2, yoff=0,
                 layout=['top', 'optimized', 'top'])
diag0.get_block((1,0)).set_facecolor('red')
diag0.get_block((1,1)).set_facecolor('purple')
diag0.get_block((1,2)).set_facecolor('green')
diag0.get_block((2,0)).set_facecolor('orange')
diag0.get_block((2,1)).set_facecolor('lightblue')
alluv.finish()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But it sent me an error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'Alluvial' from 'pyalluv'`.

Comment: Oh right! I forgot to mention: The package needs to be installed. You can simply do `pip install --upgrade --no-deps git+https://github.com/tools4digits/pyalluv.git` will add it to the answer. It uses 'numpy' and 'matplotlib' which need to be installed separately if the command is run with the `--no-deps` flag.